# Execute single test with FunSuite and Intellj

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm unsing FunSuite and IntelliJ and I would like to execute indivual test from a test class but I can't select the test I want to execute, is there any option to do that?

```
@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class MyTestIntegrationTest extends FunSuite with BeforeAndAfter with BeforeAndAfterAll with StreamingActionBase {

  override def beforeAll(): Unit = {
  }

  before {
  }

  after {
  }

  test("test1"){
  ..
  }

  test("testN"){
  ..
  }
```

I would like something be able to execute just one test, not all the tests of the class.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: Is Right-click not showing the individual tests?

Comment: No.. just runing all the class

Comment: righ click in between the scope of a test that you want to run and you will get the option for that test function to run

Comment: No, even if I run the test, pick one of them with a right-click I can't run it